# xltabular with X columns and various vertical alignments

Tags: xltabular

What do I need to change in

```
{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c *7{>{\Centering}X}}
```

to have more control over vertical alignment, say the left column is flushleft, the 3rd column r, all others to be centered?
I tried to use lrccccc in that line, but I am not sure where I should place it.

Comment: Do you want the left column centred or left aligned?

Comment: The left I want left aligned, all others can be centered. I try to understand the syntax how this works, rather than copy and past code. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Just replace `c` with `l` in the table preamble.

Comment: lol  - I thought that "c" stands for "column", I could have tried that! What is the X for at the end? And what if I want something like l r r c c  r?

Comment: `l` for left aligned, `r` for right aligned, `c` for centered. However, in `xtabular` should be at least one column `X` or derivative from it: `˙>{\RaggredRight}X` for left aligned, `>{\RaggedLeft}X` for right aligned and `>{Centering}X` for centered cells contents.  A simpler way to show this, is provide one example wgat you try so far ...

Comment: The `X`  columns share the remaining space so that the total width of the table be equal to the prescribed width (in your code `\textwidth`).